# How can I select array element using angular?

Tags: angularjs

```
   var options = [
          {name: ['black', 'green', 'black'], shade:'dark'},
          {name: ['white', 'black', 'white'], shade:'light'},
          {name: ['grey', 'white', 'yellow'], shade:'dark'},
          {name: ['red', 'black', 'red'], shade:'dark'},
          {name: ['yellow', 'green', 'black'], shade:'light'}
          ];

    var app = angular.module('module', []);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.options = options;
        $scope.$watch('myselect', function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options">
        <select ng-model="myselect" ng-options=" item for item in option.name"></select>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I am new at angular and even at web developing. 
I need to select one of the name's array element and send it to the server. I am trying to do it like this, but nothing happening. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @adrichman options variable don't have name property, it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code and they are:

- you bind all your selects to the same model `myselect`.
- initial value of `myselect` model is not set.
- in order to watch changes of object properties you should use `true` as the third parameter of `watch()`

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options">
        <select ng-model="myselect[$index]" ng-options="item for item in option.name"></select>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var options = [
  {name: ['black', 'green', 'black'], shade:'dark'},
  {name: ['white', 'black', 'white'], shade:'light'},
  {name: ['grey', 'white', 'yellow'], shade:'dark'},
  {name: ['red', 'black', 'red'], shade:'dark'},
  {name: ['yellow', 'green', 'black'], shade:'light'}
];

var app = angular.module('module', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = options;
  $scope.myselect = {}; // <= set initial value to be an empty object
  $scope.$watch('myselect', function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }, true); // <= use true as third parameter in order to watch object property changes
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpwM8Mk5okcOQcFfbl0L?p=preview) with working example.

In order to send something to the server you can use Angular's build-in [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) service.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vadim! The nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing some code like 'ng-app', and why do you add ng-repeat for div?
In fact, we only add ng-repeat for select element.

There is some example code for you:
[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/b908HpKgS8dkJ33Do2dP?p=preview)

Comment: watch console, you can see some log when you change select.